# Titanium calendar module - timezone issue in Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

When I use the code below, the event will be placed in de calendar right and will be graphically showed on the right time on the device, but when I open the event details, the event times showed are 1 hour too early.

```
var calendar = Ti.Calendar.getCalendarById(1);

// Create the event
var date1 = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3000);
var date2 = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 900000);

var details = {
  title: 'Do some stuff',
  description: "I'm going to do some stuff at this time.",
  begin: date1,
  end: date2
};

var event = calendar.createEvent(details);
```

Even when I use this: (thus with no time zone at all) it goes wrong.

```
var date1 = new Date(2016, 12, 17, 12, 0, 0);
var date2 = new Date(2016, 12, 17, 14, 0, 0);
```

I've read a lot of posts about similar questions, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Please is there anyone who can hint me to the solution?

Comment: Have you tried with momentJS? var moment = require("alloy/moment");

Comment: Sorry Rene for the very late reaction...

I'll wil try your suggestion and let know the results